# CSS on modal window not aligning

Tags: css, modal-dialog

See: http://www.myproduction-1.info/jquery%20tools%20org%20overlay/blue.html

1- I'm now sure how to get the close button to be a link.

3- The left side of the background image is partially hidden and I've looked at every possible selector to change it, but no go.

DONE 2- The entire modal window should be centered in the viewport.

Any hints would be VERY appreciated!

Comment: it's too long to paste the code here. May be firebug would work better with the link above?

Comment: Post some code
and besides that you lag a "for" selector to make the label link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code to make modal window center align.

```
.modal {
    background-color: #FBFFFF;
    display: none;
    width: 755px;
    height: 535px;
    text-align: left;
    opacity: 0.8;
    margin: -267px 0 0 -377px;
    top: 50%!important;
    left: 50%!important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what do you think about the close button? Right now it's part of the image so as to avoid potential need to position it with hacks...

Comment: Add a <a> tag and make it absolute and set the position just above the close button.